# Using a generator comprehension to create data frames

Tags: python, pandas, generator

Correct me if I'm wrong but a generator comprehension produces a generator object.  If this is the case, then why are the contents of df1, df2, df3 & df4 actual data frames and not generator objects?

```
In  [1]: import pandas as pd       
nrows, ncols = 10, 10       
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)       
df1, df2, df3, df4 = (pd.DataFrame(rng.rand(nrows, ncols)) for i in range(4))

In  [2]: df1
Out [2]:
          0         1         2  ...         7         8         9
0  0.103124  0.902553  0.505252  ...  0.010838  0.905382  0.091287
1  0.319314  0.950062  0.950607  ...  0.328665  0.672518  0.752375
2  0.791579  0.789618  0.091206  ...  0.887704  0.350915  0.117067
3  0.142992  0.761511  0.618218  ...  0.821860  0.706242  0.081349
4  0.084838  0.986640  0.374271  ...  0.753378  0.376260  0.083501
5  0.777147  0.558404  0.424222  ...  0.468661  0.056303  0.118818
6  0.117526  0.649210  0.746045  ...  0.868599  0.223596  0.963223
7  0.012154  0.969879  0.043160  ...  0.553854  0.969303  0.523098
8  0.629399  0.695749  0.454541  ...  0.280963  0.950411  0.890264
9  0.455657  0.620133  0.277381  ...  0.077735  0.974395  0.986211
```

Comment: For the same reason that `x,y = [1, 2]` makes `x` and `y` ints instead of lists... because you are *unpacking the contents of the iterable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking a generator object (by doing `a, b, c, etc. = (genexp)`) causes it to generate all of it's items then gives one item to each of the variables it unpacks to. In your case, each variable (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`, and `df4`) gets one `DataFrame` from the generator object because you unpacked the generator to those those variables.